# Porqué Github pages muestra el README y no el index.html

Tags: github, github-pages

Este es mi repositorio https://github.com/Camlo01/Website-Rentacar y quiero mostrarlo en Github pages pero sólo me muestra es el README.md

Este es el link de github pages https://camlo01.github.io/Website-Rentacar/

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que GitHub pages muestra solo proyectos web con un archivo index.html, en tu caso la aplicación debe pasar un proceso de "compilación".

Buscando un poco quizá [este enlace](https://www.lorenzobettini.it/2020/01/publishing-a-maven-site-to-github-pages/) te pueda ayudar, ya que muestra un proceso de publicación para un proyecto similar.

**NOTA** No es de mi autoría el artículo